# viewDidAppear & viewWillAppear not firing in tabbar app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In a tab bar application, I'm adding a view to my first tabbar view by doing:

```
[self.view addSubview:anotherView.view];
```

Once anotherView is done, I do:

```
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Which goes back to the parent but doesn't fire viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear on the parent.  I can use messaging but it seems there must be a better way.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a subview to the first view, it's still visible, just behind the second view. Those methods don't fire because *technically* it's visible the whole time, even if it's completely covered by the second view.

Comment: I see.  Would I then need to use messaging?  Thanks.

Comment: Either use messaging or change how you're doing this. For instance, you could set up a UINavigationController with the first view as its root view, hide its navigation bar, and push the second view controller onto it.